# Which are the fundamental stack manipulation operations?

Tags: virtual-machine, operators, stack, forth, factor

I'm creating a stack oriented virtual machine, and so I started learning Forth for a general understanding about how it would work. Then I shortlisted the essential stack manipulation operations I would need to implement in my virtual machine:

```
drop ( a -- )
dup  ( a -- a a )
swap ( a b -- b a )
rot  ( a b c -- b c a )
```

I believe that the following four stack manipulation operations can be used to simulate any other stack manipulation operation. For example:

```
nip  ( a b -- b )       swap drop
-rot ( a b c -- c a b ) rot rot
tuck ( a b -- b a b )   dup -rot
over ( a b -- a b a )   swap tuck
```

That being said however I wanted to know whether I have listed all the fundamental stack manipulation operations necessary to manipulate the stack in any possible way.

Are there any more fundamental stack manipulation operations I would need to implement, without which my virtual machine wouldn't be Turing complete?

Comment: You may be interested in Postcript as well.

Comment: Aren't some of the alternatives in your second list very dependent on the length of the stack? For example `rot rot` as an alternative for `-rot`? What happens when there are more than 3 items on the stack? Wouldn't you then have to `rot` as often as `Length-1` times to achieve `-rot`?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's why I accepted the answer @mouviciel provided. Instead of `dup`, `swap` and `rot` I use `pick ( a_n ... a_0 n -- a_n ... a_0 a_n)` and `roll ( a_n ... a_0 n i )` instead. If `i` is negative then `roll` shifts the elements to the left; else to the right.

Comment: As to the Turing completeness - you might be interested in [Are there minimum criteria for a programming language being Turing complete?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/991/are-there-minimum-criteria-for-a-programming-language-being-turing-complete) from the Computer Science Stack exchange.  CS.SE might also be a good place to ask the operations necessary for a stack machine to be Turing complete.

Comment: Note that SWAP can be implemented with DUP ROT ROT DROP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brent Kerby establishes a number of computationally complete bases of stack operations in his [Theory of Concatenative Combinators](http://tunes.org/%7Eiepos/joy.html). You need some notion of “quotation” of stack terms. Using his nomenclature, the following sets of combinators are all Turing-complete:

```
            [B] [A] cons == [[B] A]
            [B] [A] sip  == [B] A [B]
            [B] [A] k    == A

    [D] [C] [B] [A] s'   == [[D] C] A [D] B
            [B] [A] k    == A

            [B] [A] cake == [[B] A] [A [B]]
            [B] [A] k    == A

[E] [D] [C] [B] [A] j'   == [[D] A [E] B] [C] B
                [A] i    == A

            [B] [A] take == [A [B]]
            [B] [A] cat  == [B A]
                [A] i    == A

            [B] [A] cons == [[B] A]
            [B] [A] sap  == A B
```

Using my preferred nomenclature, a convenient complete set to implement is:

```
          A dup == A A
       A B swap == B A
         A drop ==
        A quote == [A]
[A] [B] compose == [A B]
      [A] apply == A
```

Comment: After reading the [Theory of Concatenative Combinators](http://tunes.org/~iepos/joy.html), I believe that the sets {`j'`, `i`}, {`take`, `cat`, `i`}, and {`cons`, `sap`} are in fact not Turing complete. The set {`j'`, `i`} is what author calls conservative complete. You can't implement `zap` (a.k.a. `pop` or `drop`) using `j'` and `i`. The sets {`take`, `cat`, `i`} and {`cons`, `sap`} are even more restrictive. These sets are what the author calls linear complete. You can't implement `zap` or `dup` using these sets.

Answer (score 5):

Many stack based languages use `roll` as well, which is a generalized `rot` on an arbitrary number of elements in the stack. They also implement the reverse operation for rotating the stack the other way.

I would say that `roll` is more fundamental than `rot`.

I have no answer though about *Turingness* of this.

Comment: without references of some kind to arbitrary memory the only thing you have is a [PDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automata) note that roll will will satisfy turing completeness if you can query the size of the stack so you can access arbitrary element on the stack